# Just installed some updates for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Vmware, now desktop won't show

Tags: unity, compiz

I just installed some normal updates through the auto-updater - I've never had a problem doing this.

After restarting my virtual machine (using vmware player), the desktop no longer shows. When I enter TTY1 it said VMware tools had failed so I uninstalled it. The desktop still doesn't show.

I've tried re-enabling Unity through the compizconfig-setting-manager and that doesn't work either.

I'm worried I'm going to have to make a new virtual machine at this rate.

Thank you

[edit] I just logged in through a Xubuntu session and that seems to work - so at least I can get my files off the machine. So this could be a gnome / unity issue.

Comment: Make sure that [VMware tools are installed](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017687)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a physical Ubuntu 14 system.

As a workaround, try running unity from the dollar prompt, which worked for me. (You may need to get a text login via Crtl-Alt-F1 - if so, switch back via Alt-F7)

Comment: Final fix was: sudo apt-get remove unity ; sudo apt-get install unity